# Display sale price only for logged in customer

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, price

I want to know how to hide sale price  and keep orginal price  for visitor and show sale price  only for registered customer i woocommerce.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have child-theme, create it and then in functions.php add this code:

add_action( 'init', 'hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in' );

```
function hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in() {   
   if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {      
      remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
      remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
      remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
      remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );   
      add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'print_login_to_see', 31 );
      add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'print_login_to_see', 11 );
   }
}
  
function print_login_to_see() {
   echo '<a href="' . get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">' . __('Login to see prices', 'theme_name') . '</a>';
}
```

Don't forget to replace "theme_name" by yours.

Source: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-hide-price-add-cart-logged-users/